# Plaid Transaction endpoint in nodejs

Tags: plaid

I am unable to pull the transactions from plai using nodejs and express.

I am able to pull bank account information and balance.

It seems app.get is not working. I mean , if I console log transactions I get undefined and nothing shows in the web browser.

Is there anyone who could give me an app.get function to pull the transactions and show them in the console or the browser? I can make it work for the accounts and auth, but not for transactions.

Thank you

I tried creating a special route
/gettransactions using plaidclient and transactionssync.

Answer (score 0):

The [Plaid Quickstart](https://github.com/plaid/quickstart) has sample code for an end-to-end transactions integration using Node.js and Express. You should be able to get a working example from there.